# Remove special characters in regex PHP that allow accented words and chinese language

Tags: php, regex, special-characters, non-ascii-characters

I need a solution that remove all special characters except alphanumeric and accents. I tryed this solution without success.

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-ZáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚâêîôÂÊÎÔãõÃÕçÇ0-9_ \.&-]/s', '', $string);
```

Furthermore, its need that regex (or other specific solution) allow chinese and arabian charset.

any help its really apprecieted!

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Comment: So what exactly *are* "special characters"? *"Remove everything except a few selected ones and this whole giant block of other characters which make up the majority of Unicode"* is a bit vague. *Why* do you need to remove those characters?

Comment: Im building a search text field than I need clean keywords from "/%$@* and more...

Comment: What's so special about "/%$@*, why can't people search for those characters? Why only "alphanumeric, accents, Chinese and Arabian", what about, say, Korean, Japanese and Sanskrit?

Comment: because there are not results from those characters

Comment: yes I need allow all languages

Comment: So what exactly don't you allow then? Look at the link above by CBroe. Sounds like `\pL` may be what you want, but that's honestly hard to tell.

Comment: Will there be any results for "aslkgjalkgjaljgaslkjg"? No? Then display 0 results. Will there be any results for Chinese characters? No? Then display 0 results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\PL/u', '', $string);
```

- `L` is a character attribute meaning *letter*
- `\P` means *does **not** match attribute*
- `/u` is the Unicode modifier, you need this if you want to handle Unicode characters
- make sure `$string` is encoded in UTF-8

So this matches *all non-letters* and removes them. I can only guess that this matches what you want. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php for more attributes you could match by, e.g. `/[^\pL\pS]/u` would match everything except letters and "symbols".

Comment: If you need to play around with what matches what, see here: http://rubular.com/r/WcotUy4ju9. (Note that this regex engine requires you to write `\p{L}` instead of `\pL`.)

Comment: excellent! thanks and congratulations!

Comment: if Do I need exclude space?

Comment: Add it to the group in my second example. Either just `\s` or `\pZ`.

Comment: $string = preg_replace('\pL\pS/u', '', $string);  is it correct?

Comment: No, that matches a Letter *followed by* a Symbol. As I wrote: `/[^\pL\pS]/u`.

Comment: I wrote so but now work:
preg_replace('/[^\pL\pS]/u', '', $string)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo preg_replace('/[^أ-يA-Za-z0-9 ]/ui', '', $string);
```

Comment: not work. its ok for special characters but remove foreign language symbols too.